# Firebase Database won't display any value

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have great issues on writing in my database in Firebase. Nothing would be written. Also, when I press the button, I only get the debug string "button clicked!" but not the other two strings in case of success or failure(nothing happens). The rules of the database are true for read and true for write. Here is my code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_user_infos)

    var namefield = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.name_form_edit_text)
    var surnamefield = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.surname_form_edit_text)
    var agefield = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.age_form_edit_text)
    var button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.submit_button)
    var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
    val uid = intent.getStringExtra("user_id").toString()

    button.setOnClickListener {
        var name = namefield.text.toString()
        var surname = surnamefield.text.toString()
        var age = agefield.text.toString().toInt()

        Toast.makeText(
             this@UserInfosActivity,
             "Button clicked!",
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
        ).show()

        database.child("users").child(uid).setValue(User(name, surname, age)).addOnSuccessListener {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@UserInfosActivity,
                    "Success",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
            .addOnFailureListener {
                Toast.makeText(
                    this@UserInfosActivity,
                    "Fail",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
       }
   }
}
```

My User class is:

```
data class User(val name:String, val surname:String, val age:Int){ constructor(): this("","",0) }
```

Comment: My User class is: data class User(val name:String, val surname:String, val age:Int){
    constructor(): this("","",0)
}

Comment: Instead of adding that information as a comment (where most people won't see it), please edit your question by clicking the link right under it.

Comment: This typically means that your device can't reach the database, for example which might mean it doesn't have an internet connection. Check that, and if you're still having problem [enable debug logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/FirebaseDatabase.html#setLogLevel(com.google.firebase.database.Logger.Level)) and check the logcat output around the call to `setValue`.

Comment: Have you tried Frank van Puffelen's suggestion?

Comment: I just tried it and I got on Logcat (without even pressing the button), " Firebase Database connection was forcefully killed by the server. Will not attempt reconnect. Reason: Database lives in a different region. Please change your database URL to... [url of my DB]".
I think the fault is in the line var database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference...

Comment: I tried to connect to Firebase Database using only the url, but now it just shows on this line: 
database.child("users").child(uid).setValue(User(name, surname, age)).addOnSuccessListener {...

Unresolved reference: child

Comment: Ok! I finally solved by just adding .getReference() after connecting with url to my database! Now my Database finally writes values! Thanks van Puffelen, without the Logcat I would have never discovered this error.